# Kotlin - How to generify recursive functions that can't be reified?

Tags: generics, recursion, kotlin

I want to generify the following function:

```
fun ViewGroup.allRadioButtons(f: (RadioButton) -> Unit){
    this.afterMeasured {
        for(i in 0 until childCount){
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            if(child is RadioButton){
                f(child)
            }
            if(child is ViewGroup){
                child.allRadioButtons(f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of hardcoding `RadioButton`, I would like to use a generic `T`, like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> ViewGroup.allViewsOfTypeT(f: (T) -> Unit){
    this.afterMeasured {
        for(i in 0 until childCount){
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            if(child is T){
                f(child)
            }
            if(child is ViewGroup){
                child.allRadioButtons(f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't do the above because reified types are not allowed in recursive functions.

How can I generify that function in Kotlin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the recursive function non-inline and take a `KClass` representing the desired type, and make an additional wrapper function:

```
fun <T : View> ViewGroup.allViewsOfTypeT(type: KClass<T>, f: (T) -> Unit) {
    afterMeasured {
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            if (type.isInstance(child)) f(child)
            if (child is ViewGroup) child.allViewsOfTypeT(type, f)
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : View> ViewGroup.allViewsOfTypeT(f: (T) -> Unit)
    = allViewsOfTypeT(T::class, f)
```

You can't inline a recursive function, unless you can unroll it into a loop, because inlining a function means that after compilation it *isn't* a function anymore - it is instead copied directly into the call site. No function, no call stack, no recursion. In these cases, you have to pass a `KClass` instead of making the generic parameter reified, which is basically exactly what you'd do in Java if you needed an `instanceof` check with a generic parameter.

However, you *can* roll your own stack ([Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)):

```
inline fun <reified T : View> ViewGroup.allViewsOfTypeT(action: (T) -> Unit) {
    val views = Stack<View>()

    afterMeasured {
        views.addAll((0 until childCount).map(this::getChildAt))
    }

    while (!views.isEmpty()) {
        views.pop().let {
            if (it is T) action(it)
            if (it is ViewGroup) {
                afterMeasured {
                    views.addAll((0 until childCount).map(this::getChildAt))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but the general idea should work.

Comment: Hi, it tried implementing this and the `addViews` method spits an error that says `local functions are not yet supported in inline functions`. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: @DaleJulian Oops. The only reason I used a function was to make things more readable, you can just replace the function call by its contents (or extract it and make it `private`)

Comment: thanks! But just to clarify, the `afterMeasured` method that you used here is the same as the one found here: https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-ongloballayoutlistener/ ?

Comment: @DaleJulian I'm not sure, I just used that function since the OP used it (the `afterMeasured {}` part _is_ the recurring part of the function, you can replace it with anything). It doesn't have anything to do with recursive `inline` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You may define a function within an inline function.

```
inline fun <reified T> execute64(crossinline run: (Class<*>, Int) -> Unit) {
    var cnt = 0
    val x = object : Consumer<Int> {
        override fun accept(i: Int) {
            if(i > 1) {
                repeat(2) { accept(i shr 1) }
                return
            }
            run(T::class.java, cnt++)
        }
    }
    x.accept(64)
}
```

See [this working test](https://pl.kotl.in/rkBOIx7BE)

Note that it does not require tail recursion, i.e. it will work even with NP-hard recursive algorithms.

Why it works:

- In each call to `execute64`, a new anonymous class is created inline.
- The anonymous class allows us to define a function inside a function.
- We have an actual compiled function (not just an inline function). So we can call this function recursively without worrying about inline, because the `inline`d scope is outside the scope of this function.

Note:

- This would result in defining a new anonymous class every time you call `execute64()`. So if you have 100 places in your code that call this function directly, 100 anonymous classes will be created. Your code may suffer from slow classloading. (citation needed, I am not an expert in classloading)
- This method still involves calling a method recursively, and instantiates one instance every time the inline function `execute64` is called (but no new instance is created during recursion). I am not sure if this inline function still enjoys the performance boost from inlining lambdas, but it certainly fixes the issue with `reified`.